# how to compare two numbers with selenium and java? (One number from CSV file and another in website)

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, compare, assert

I wrote a Program to compare prices in website with a csv file with selenium and java, at the end of program i wrote assert to confirm two numbers but it has a problem:
expected price is 57,15
Actual price is 57.15

Actual Price should be 57,15 and i dont know how should i write that, Can you please help me?

```
@Test(priority = 1)
void checkBeschädigung() throws FileNotFoundException {
    prepareTest();
    List<CsvPrice> stuff = readFromCSV("resources/price/BikePrice.csv");

    
    Select price = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("coverageSum")));
    price.selectByIndex(1);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"landingApp\"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/label/input")).click();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WebElement FirstPrice = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product-configurator-spinner']//parent::span"));
    String finalprice = FirstPrice.getText().split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println(finalprice);


    for (int i = 0; i <= 329; i++) {

        if (String.valueOf(stuff.get(i).getCoverageSum()).equals("250")
                && String.valueOf(stuff.get(i).getDurationStart()).equals("1") && stuff.get(i).getQualityName().equals("Diebstahl")
                && stuff.get(i).getDurationTimeUnit().equals("YEARS")) {
            System.out.println(stuff.get(i).getPriceBasePrice());
            Assert.assertEquals(finalprice, String.valueOf(stuff.get(i).getPriceBasePrice()));
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("that is wrong");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below codes before assertion line to change "." to "," in your string data:

```
String actualValueWithComa = String.valueOf(stuff.get(i).getPriceBasePrice()).replaceAll(".",",");            
Assert.assertEquals(finalprice, actualValueWithComa));
```

Comment: Thank you but insted of replaceall i wrote replace and it wokrs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to modify the test data in your CSV file.
In case you try to replace the '.' with ',' you might run into the issue while validating cases with higher value data with decimal points.
There values might be shown with commas to separate thousands place etc. Eg: 5,10,000.50